# Mysql, data migration between databases/servers (migrate now with regular updates later)

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is somewhat of an abstract question but hopefully pretty simple at the same time. I just have no idea the best way to go about this except for an export/import and I can't do that due to permission issues. So i need some alternatives.

On one server, we'll call it `1.2.3` I have a database with 2 schemas, `Rdb` and `test`. These schemas have 27 and 3 tables respectively. This database stores call info from our phone system but we have reader access only so we're very limited in what we can do beyond selecting and joining for data records and info.

I then have a production database server, call it `3.2.1` With my main schemas and I'd like to place the previous 30 tables into one of these production schemas. After the migration is done, I'll need to create a script that will check the data on the first connection and then update the new schema on the production connection, but that's after the bulk migration is done.

I'm wondering if a php script would be the way to go about this initial migration, though. I'm using MySQL workbench and the export wizard fails for the read only database, but if there's another way in the interface then I don't know about it.

It's quite a bit of data, and I'm not necessarily looking for the fastest way but the easiest and most fail safe way.

Comment: Master/slave replication?

Comment: I'm not very familiar but it sounds like it would be a good route. How would I preform that in mysql workbench though?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication

Comment: Thank you! Mysql is already installed on both servers so I'll start with step 3 and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one time data move, the easiest way is to use the command line tool `mysqldump` to dump your tables to file, then load the resulting file with `mysql`.  This assumes that you are either shutting down `1.2.3`, or will reconfigure your `phone system` to point to `3.2.1` (or update DNS appropriately).  Also, this is much easier if you can get downtime on the phone system to move the data.

> we have reader access only so we're very limited in what we can do beyond selecting and joining for data records

This really limits your options.

- Master/Slave replication requires `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege, which you probably need a user with `SUPER` privilege to create a replication user.
- Trigger based replication solutions like [SymetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org%20%22SymetricDS) will require a user with `CREATE ROUTINE` in order to create the triggers
- An "Extract, Transform, Load" solution like [Clover ETL](http://www.cloveretl.com) will work best if tables have `LAST_CHANGED` timestamps.  If they don't, then you would need `ALTER TABLE` privilege.

Different tools for different goals.

- Master/Slave replication is generally used for Disaster Recovery, Availability or Read Scaling
- Hetergenous Replication to replicate some (or all) tables between different environments (could be different RDBMS, or different replica sets) in a continuous, but asynchronous fashion.
- ETL for bulk, hourly/daily/periodic data movements, with the ability to pick a subset of columns, aggregate, convert timestamp formats, merge with multiple sources, and generally fix whatever you need to with the data.

That should help you determine really what your situation is - whether it's a one time load with a temporary data sync, or if it's an on-going replication (real-time, or delayed).

Edit:
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/index.html
Check out the Persona Toolkit.  Specifically pt-table-sync and pt-table-checksum.  They will help with this.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. After discussing with my team more, We think we would probably leave the current database and just create a script in php to run ever 15 minutes or so that will check for updates, but initially I could run this same script to select all from each table and then insert into our new tables on our server. Is there a known-good way to do that in a php script?

Comment: My experience is from the DBA perspective.  I don't know any php.  I do know that there are already tools out there for what you're trying to do.  See my edit for pt-table-sync.  You might want to try that out, could save you a lot of effort if it works for you.  Also, the initial load is a one like shell command "mysqldump <options> | mysql <options".  You don't need a php script for that.

Comment: I'm looking into pt-table-sync now and that may be a good route to take once I investigate it a bit more. It should definitely save some effor/time!

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I didn't have much luck on that tool but I did find a sql tool  that would copy from one connection to another